# How much do we learn about a random subset?

Tags: entropy, combinatorics, mutual-information

Suppose we sample the following two random variables, for some large integer $n$:

1. Let random variable $X_1$ be a uniformly random subset of $m$ elements chosen from set $[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$, where $m < n$.
2. Let random variable $X_2$ be a uniformly random subset of $k$ elements of $X_1$, where $k<m$.

In other words, $X_2$ is a random subset of $X_1$, and $X_1$ is a random subset of $[n]$.

**My Question:** Does it hold that, for any random variable $Y$ such that $I[ X_2 : Y] = H[X_2]$, the amount of information that $Y$ contains about $X_2$ is never larger than the amount of information that it reveals about $X_1$?
Formally,
$$
I[ X_2 : Y ] ≤ I[ X_1 : Y ] ? 
$$

I think this should be true, because whatever we learn from $Y$ about $X_2$ is also "useful" information about $X_1$. But how can I formalize this intuition?

Comment: Because you appear to equate random variables with subsets--which is not standard--and you haven't even mentioned a probability distribution, your question looks incomprehensible.  Could you explain what your terms and notation mean?